# Welcome. Can you give me a code that gives me an error message if it does not connect to a database via a local network

Tags: vb.net

Welcome. Can you give me a code that gives me an error message if it does not connect to a database via a local network.
Note: The program is to create an account via Visual Basic connected to a database on a local network

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data source=Younis-PC\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial catalog=account; User ID=sa; Password=12345678;")
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

     Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Make sure that the user name or password is not empty")
                Return
            End If
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table_1 where username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("This user name is already used by Please use another name")
            Else
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table_1 (username, passwords) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')", con)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                TextBox1.Text = ""
                TextBox2.Text = ""
                Me.Hide()
                acuser.Show()
                MsgBox("Account created")
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using ADO.NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Anyway, if the attempt to connect fails, your code will throw an exception and crash. If you want to make that more user-friendly, then catch the exception (using try/catch), log it (so you can investigate it later) and then display a messagebox to the user with a non-technical explanation. You can also keep the application running if you want, and re-try the connection (or give the user a button to do so), and/or tell them where they can get technical support if the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data objects local so you can close and dispose of them properly. Using blockes accomplish this even if there is an error.

Using If Exists has a few advantages.

1. It requires only a single hit to the database.
2. It will return as soon as it finds a match which will speed things
   up on a large table
3. Only a single piece of data is returned not a whole record.

**Always** use parameters to avoid Sql Injection. You will have to check the datatypes I used (only guesses) with your database.

Connections are precious resources. Only open the connection directly before the Execute. The End Using will close and dispose the connection.

To answer your question I have put a `Try...Catch...End Try` around the `con.Open()`. You can also put one around the Execute to see if the query worked.

In a real application you would **NEVER** store passwords as plain text. Note the most recent Facebook scandal.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure that the user name or password is not empty")
        Return
    End If
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim query = "If Exists(Select 1 From Table_1 where username = @username) 
                Select 0 Else Select 1 
                Insert Table_1 (username, passwords) Values (@usename, @passwords);"
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data source=Younis-PC\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial catalog=account; User ID=sa; Password=12345678;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@passwords", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Try
                con.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Error - " & ex.Message)
                Return
            End Try
            Result = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If Result = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("This user name is already used by Please use another name")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Account created")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        acuser.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```